# Write output of multiple batch commands to one line of a text file

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd

It's pretty self-explanatory, what I'm trying to do here.
When I do something like this:

```
set n=0
:choose
set /a n+=1
choice /c yn
if errorlevel 2 ( echo NO! >>log.txt
) else echo YES! >>log.txt
if %n% lss 10 goto choose
```

The loop executes produces a new line for each time the command is executed (10 times=10 lines)
I want it to write all 10 outputs to one line in the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set n=0
:choose
set /a n+=1
choice /c yn
if errorlevel 2 ( echo|set /p=NO! >>log.txt
) else echo|set /p=YES! >>log.txt
if %n% lss 10 goto choose
```